# How to verify that data in a field is of a certain DATA_TYPE with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to pull a really big chunk of data from a Postgres server. Before doing so I want to make sure that the data I pull has the right type (it can be text or binary).

So I need to somehow peek at data on the server with an SQL query, if its the right type, return true, else return false. (This peeking with an SQL also allows me make sure that the server is actually properly ready to process queries).

But after a long time trying I just cannot get my head around how compose the SQL query for this!

Comment: A given query on a given table will always return the same type. So what's the variable here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends a lot on details you've left out. Usually the application will know the data type of fields it is querying in advance. If it doesn't there are a variety of reasons why it might not, and the appropriate choice depends a bit on the reason.

Options include:

- If you know the schema, table and column name, look it up in  [the `information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html), e.g.

  ```
  select data_type, is_nullable 
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'test' and column_name = 'f';
  ```

  This works on most databases, it isn't PostgreSQL specific.
- Some client drivers expose database and/or query metadata - for example, in PgJDBC you can [use `DatabaseMetaData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to get information about the database, or even specific queries. Again, this is not PostgreSQL specific.
- If you only have the SQL query, and are working with a low level driver like `libpq`, send a `Describe` protocol message. The server will reply with the data types and sizes. You *cannot* do this at the SQL level, only at the protocol level.
- You can use the `pg_typeof` function to get the type of a particular scalar value